# When does group homomorphism imply quasi-isometric

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, geometric-group-theory

[image]

I could not find a good source for this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Definition:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

A group homomorphism $f \colon G \to H$ between two finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$ is a quasi-isometry if and only if $ker(f)$ is finite **and** $im(f)$ has finite index in $H$. The proof is probably a good exercise (but not too hard after all).

This gives a characterization depending on the morphism $f$ in question.

The characterization you wrote does *not* involve the morphism $f$. Take e.g. two infinite finitely generated virtually isomorphic groups as you wrote and let $f$ be the trivial morphism. Then the groups are clearly quasi-isometric but $f$ is certainly not a quasi-isometry.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
Can you please also help with the proof. I am really struggling with it.

Comment: I have tried all sort of things. 
I know that ker(f) is subnormal group of G. Im(f) is sub group of H.
I am having trouble trying to show the quasi isometric equality, since i don't know what the metric is..

Comment: The metric you are working with is the so called *word-metric* w.r.t a generating set. Write down the full definition of a $(c,b)$-quasi isometry and you should easily see why the kernel and the index $[im(f):H]$ is finite.

Comment: OK, I've added the definition of (C,D)-quasi-isometric. If  x1,x2 are in ker(f) and the inequality in the definition holds. How do I seek that ker(f) is finite?

Comment: If $x_1, x_2 \in ker(f)$ then the *left* inequality tells you that their distance w.r.t $d_S$ is **bounded**, indeed it is $\leq CD$. Hence they can only be finitely many as your group is finitely generated.

Comment: .... btw for the definition of a quasi isometry you need to add another property: your map f has to have a quasi dense image. Looking at this property you will probably see why it is equivalent to im(f) having finite index (in the case when f is a group morphism). ... a quasi isometry is a map which is a quasi isometric embedding **and** has quasi dense image.